# How to change nginx configuration context URI for odoo

Tags: nginx, url, runtime-error, uri, odoo-15

My odoo15 works fine for this URL -> https://vidatest.xyz and below is the nginx configuration as suggested by odoo documentation.

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
  server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
  server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

# http -> https
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name vidatest.xyz;
  rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name vidatest.xyz;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

  # SSL parameters
  ssl_certificate /etc/certs/certs_14March2022/98fa7f5df02b430e.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/generated-private-key.key;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;


  # log
  access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
  location /longpolling {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
  }

  # common gzip
  gzip_types text/css text/scss text/plain text/xml application/xml application/json application/javascript;
  gzip on;
}
```

However, my requirement is to use `https://vidatest.xyz` not for odoo but for my application.

odoo should work on this URL -> `https://vidatest.xyz/web`

Thus, I updated & added the below changes to the nginx configuration

```
  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location /web {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://mybank.com;
  }
```

Now, odoo is loading for this URL -> `https://vidatest.xyz/web` but throws the below error after successful login

[image]

Error stack:

```
POST https://vidatest.xyz/mail/init_messaging 405 (Not Allowed)
POST https://vidatest.xyz/longpolling/poll 405 (Not Allowed)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (web.assets_backend.min.js:585:55)
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend.min.js:585
load (async)
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend.min.js:583
jsonrpc @ web.assets_backend.min.js:582
rpc @ web.assets_backend.min.js:590
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend.min.js:3324
legacyEnv.session.rpc @ web.assets_backend.min.js:3323
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.min.js:5057
rpc @ web.assets_common.min.js:5057
_trigger_up @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5924
trigger_up @ web.assets_common.min.js:4855
call @ web.assets_common.min.js:4908
_rpc @ web.assets_common.min.js:4908
_makePoll @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5914
_poll @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5914
startPolling @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5913
startPolling @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5893
prototype.<computed> @ web.assets_common.min.js:4716
_startElection @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5900
startPolling @ web.assets_backend.min.js:5890
```

Odoo & python versions:

```
root@ip-172-31-42-237:/var/log# systemctl status odoo
● odoo.service - Odoo15
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/odoo.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-04-06 10:26:20 UTC; 6min ago
   Main PID: 420828 (python3)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 4623)
     Memory: 138.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/odoo.service
             └─420828 /opt/odoo/odoo-venv/bin/python3 /opt/odoo/odoo/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo.conf -u vida_product

python3 --version
Python 3.8.10

/usr/bin/pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Comment: 2 questions : 1. This error stack - is this taken after clicking the button on error in the screenshot or from the server logs?  2. The POST 405 errors that appear in the logs, are they expected or are they part of the problem?

Comment: 1. This error stack - this is taken after clicking the login button on odoo login page in the browser's inspect -> console 2. I m not aware of 405 error but a simple odoo install and access via `http://<hostname>/web` through nginx is my requirement. See if that works.

Comment: You might need to inform your application about the change of its location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a bit tricky. You may not be able to achieve it because Odoo uses /web as the main denominator to forward to backend. You are trying to serve:

- `https://vidatest.xyz` - another website
- `https://vidatest.xyz/web` - odoo

But Odoo uses the full domain or the subdomain as its own and manages it as such. That is why you are getting below error.

```
POST https://vidatest.xyz/mail/init_messaging 405 (Not Allowed)
POST https://vidatest.xyz/longpolling/poll 405 (Not Allowed)
```

Your problem is more of a Nginx problem rather than an Odoo problem. The easiest solution is to put Odoo in a subdomain and serve whatever you want from the main domain. For example: `https://odoo.vidatest.xyz` Than each call Odoo makes would be to that subdomain.

If you insist the way you want to deploy, check `web.base.url` key parameter in `Settings > Technical > System Parameters` after enabling *developer mode*. Set the value to the full domain you want to use, if it doesn't exists create it. And also add another parameter with key `web.base.url.freeze` and value `True`. See if that works for you. If it doesn't you may need to redirect the referred calls from Nginx to the full path you are using. Also, you may need to set the path of the longpolling port to work with `/web/longpolling` as well. I am not sure but final working version might be `https://vidatest.xyz/web/web` so it should be tricky.